# Dynamically adding Html elements inside an Html doc added into XUL

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm trying to create a Firefox extension using the same html files I used to chrome extension. 
With some Google search, I found a way to use

```
xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

As namespace and to use the html file which I used in chrome as it is and its working fine. Now, I want to add elements dynamically into that html file using JavaScript. For example

```
var testdiv=document.getElementById('test');
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute("innerText", "test");
testdiv.appendChild(a);
```

But this is not giving the expected out put. Any suggestions on this or any other way to do this??

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL_Tutorial/Modifying_a_XUL_Interface

Comment: This is to add xul elements dynamically. I need to add html elements inside html doc which is a part of xul document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create elements in a namespace, you have to use [`document.createElementNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElementNS) method. So in your case, creating the A element would look like this:

```
var a = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'a');
```